# Heroku ModuleNoteFoundError with django-qr-code

Tags: python, django, heroku, backend

I am currently working on the Backend of my small application.
During deployment, I am getting the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qr_code'

I am not using the pypi qrcode library, instead I am using the django-qr-code library
https://django-qr-code.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/README.html

My Requirements.txt

```
> asgiref==3.5.0
backports.entry-points-selectable==1.1.1
certifi==2021.10.8
distlib==0.3.4
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==4.0.3
django-heroku==0.0.0
django-qr-code==3.0.0
filelock==3.4.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
Pillow==9.0.1
pipenv==2021.11.23
platformdirs==2.4.0
segno==1.4.1
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
virtualenv==20.10.0
virtualenv-clone==0.5.7
whitenoise==6.0.0
```

My settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'sendqr',
'qr_code',
]
```

Somehow Heroku can't seem to properly find the django-qr-code library even though it is inside of my requirements.txt. Is there a way to maybe manually push it onto the heroku server or something?

Comment: Your setup looks correct. Are you sure that requirements.txt is up to date in your repo? Did you check the heroku logs after you pushed changes to your repo? In the logs you can see which package versions were installed and if errors occure.

Comment: In the meantime, I got it fixed. The issue was, that Heroku ignored my requirements.txt because I am using pipenv. I simply installed django-qr-code on the pipenv and the pipenv.lock and it worked. Thank you tho